# Remove instances of words following a character in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, string, text

I'm trying to preprocess message data from the StockTwits API, how can I remove all instances of $name from a string in python?

For example if the string is:

```
$AAPL $TSLA $MSFT are all going up!
```

The output would be:

```
are all going up!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this would do:

```
>>> s = "$AAPL $TSLA $MSFT are all going up!"
>>> re.sub(r"\$[a-zA-Z0-9]+\s*", "", s)
'are all going up!'
```

This allows numbers in the name as well, remove `0-9` if that's not what you want (it would remove e.g. `$15` as well).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I get it, but If I'm to remove all instances of words that start with `$`, I would break into individual strings, then look for `$`, and re-form using a list comprehension.

```
substrings = string.split(' ')
substrings = [s for s in substrings if not s.startswith('$')]
new_string = ' '.join(substrings)
```

Some would use regular expressions, which are likely more computationally efficient, but less easy to read.